# Is there a type-safe list-ref function provided by Typed Racket?

Tags: list, racket, type-safety, typed-racket

Is there a type-safe `list-ref` function provided by Typed Racket?

The `list-ref` function appears to throw an error if you try to access an index that is out of bounds:

```lisp
> (require typed/racket)
> (list-ref '(1 2 3) 100)
; list-ref: index too large for list
;   index: 100
;   in: '(1 2 3)
```

It makes sense that `list-ref` returns an error given its type:

```lisp
> list-ref
- : (All (a) (-> (Listof a) Integer a))
```

I would imagine that a type-safe version would have a type like the following:

```lisp
(: list-ref (All (a) (-> (Listof a) Integer (Option a)))
```

---

If this type-safe `list-ref` function is provided somewhere from Typed Racket, how would I have gone about finding it?

If this type-safe `list-ref` function doesn't exist, then why not?  It seems like this function would be generally useful.

Comment: It is uncommon to access list elements by index. And when one does, one often already knows the index is good (possibly by construction, possibly by checking it earlier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't exist as far as I know.

One problem with your proposed `(All (a) (-> (Listof a) Integer (Option a)))` is that `(Option a)` is simply `(U #f a)`. That is, you must represent "none" with `#f`. But if you have a `(Listof Boolean)`, and `list-ref*` (your variant of `list-ref`) returns `#f`, how can you tell if it's because to the index is out of bounds, or because the element is truly `#f`?

One possible way to fix this problem is by wrapping the "some" variant with something like a box, and adjust the type accordingly. E.g.,

```
(: list-ref* (All (a) (-> (Listof a) Integer (Option (Boxof a)))))
(define (list-ref* xs i)
  (with-handlers ([exn:fail? (λ (_) #f)])
    (box (list-ref xs i))))
```

Mind you that wrapping will affect performance, and this might explain why it's not included in the library.

Comment: I agree that wrapping with a [`Maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#t:Maybe)-like value would be more explicit than [`Option`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/type-ref.html?q=Option#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fbase-types..rkt%29._.Option%29%29), but there do appear to be other functions in the standard library that share this same ambiguity: [`findf`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._findf%29%29): `(All (a) (-> (-> a Boolean) (Listof a) (Option a)))`.